# Can't log in to desktop

Tags: login, desktop-environments

I can't log in to my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop any more.  Other accounts show no login problems.
I can, however, login to the same account from the terminal (ctrl-alt-f6) or ssh. I can also log in as root to the desktop. I have checked and reset the password, rebooted etc. but to no avail.
What can I do?
H

Thanks
I have 11 GB in my home directory and I am using the right keyboard input language and CapsLk is off but still no login.
H

Comment: Check you have space in $HOME (ie. your user directory).  If there is insufficient space for work files required by your GUI, you'll be logged out - however terminal logins (inc. `ssh` remotely) will still work.

Comment: Check the keyboard input language when typing the password.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:
1) backup the files in my home directory
2) delete my user
3) add same new user
4) restore files to my home directory
Why login now works is, however, a mystery